# SharePoint Error The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I am working on a Sharepoint Application with Office 365. It is an Auto Hosted App and I want to get the file (excel) stream from document library so i can use openXML to perform further operations. I am getting the exception **"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."**

here is the code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = GetTheFileFromTheDocLibrary("excelfile.xlsx");

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(Session["SPHostUrl"].ToString());
            FileInformation fInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            // The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            { // other code
```

Note: the same code is working in a Provider Hosted Application.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend moving away from Auto-Hosted as soon as possible based on the announcement that we made last month http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/

Provider Hosted Apps are the way to go for your scenario and you say there is no error which is great news.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Provider Hosted App and it was a missed, wrong or empty ClientId inside the .config file.

Example:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientId" value="xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx" />
...
</appSettings>
```